# MySQL random updating madness

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a procedure `mst2` which creates a minimum spanning tree and updates a table `MST` in my database with several values. It works fine with WAMP but acts crazy when I try to import it on a live server.

Currently, every time I reload the table random values appear in it and seem to go up and down?? I have no idea what's going on. I'm not even calling the function but the table appears to be dynamically adjusting constantly.

I would post my code but it might be overkill, it's pretty extensive. If anybody has a general idea about what can cause this please let me know.

Comment: It keeps growing.. currently 377 tuples

Comment: Debugging Stored Procedures are difficult. I'd suggest to switch to plain SQL to see what is going on there.

Comment: This really can't be answered without seeing the code.  Perhaps you can find a small part where the problem is and post it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that I was referencing the table in lowercase as `'mst'` in some parts of the code relying on the fact that MySQL isn't case sensitive. Apparently the server I was importing to (Linux) had MySQL configured to be case sensitive for table (and possibly column?) names, fixing the table name in the code from lower to upper solved the issue.